# Why is my bullet not following my player?

Tags: python, pygame

So I have a problem, I am making a shooter game but when I make the projectiles the bullet doesn't follow the player.btw I'm doing this in python. here's main.py:

```
import pygame
from player import *

pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 600
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shooter Game")

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

player_x = 500
player_y = 440
PLAYER_WIDTH = PLAYER_HEIGHT = 60
PLAYER_VEL = 5

BULLET_VEL = 10

keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
player_rect = pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT)
player = Player(WIN, RED, player_rect, keys_pressed, PLAYER_VEL)

def draw(bullets):
    WIN.fill(WHITE)
    for bullet in bullets:
        pygame.draw.rect(WIN, BLACK, bullet)

def handle_bullets(bullets):
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.y -= BULLET_VEL
        if bullet.y > HEIGHT:
            bullets.remove(bullet)

FPS = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def main():
    run = True

    bullets = []
    
    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LALT:
                    bullet = pygame.Rect(player_x + PLAYER_WIDTH//2, player_y, 5, 10)
                    bullets.append(bullet)

        print(bullets)
        draw(bullets)
        player.draw_player()
        player.move()
        handle_bullets(bullets)
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and main.py is the script that I'm having problems with. Cuz you see I have a bullet = []
and when the bullet is created it's at the player's y and x but it doesn't follow the player. so like when you first shoot and not move, it'll shoot in the correct place.But once you move, the bullet stays in the first position. and this is my player.py script:

```
    import pygame

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, surface, color, player, keys_pressed, vel):
        self.surface = surface
        self.color = color
        self.player = player
        self.keys_pressed = keys_pressed
        self.vel = vel
    def draw_player(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, self.color, self.player)
    def move(self):
        self.keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if self.keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and self.player.y > self.vel:
            self.player.y -= self.vel
        if self.keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and self.player.y < 600 - self.player.height:
            self.player.y += self.vel
        if self.keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and self.player.x > self.vel:
            self.player.x -= self.vel
        if self.keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and self.player.x < 900 - self.player.width:
            self.player.x += self.vel
```

Comment: You never update the bullet's x coordinate. If you want it to follow the player, you need to update the x coordinate in the `handle_bullet` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use hardcoded value of player starting coordinates.
Change line under ALT key action:

```
bullet = pygame.Rect(player.player.x + PLAYER_WIDTH // 2, player.player.y, 5, 10)
```

Comment: but now it doesn't delete the bullet but it does fix that problem. Can you find a way to delete the bullet noe?

Comment: coordinates in pygame work from top left to top right - so the line when you check if bullet.y is greater than height will never be true (assuming that you will never rotate player). Just change it to if bullet.y < 0. That's because coordinate y=0 is top of your screen.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your bullets come out of the same location is because the `player_x` and `player_y` variables are never updated.

When you draw your bullet you use them, and that's all well and good

```py
bullet = pygame.Rect(player_x + PLAYER_WIDTH//2, player_y, 5, 10)
```

but you never update the player's position.

I think you mean to include the following lines in your `def move(self):` method:

```
    def move(self):
        self.keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if self.keys_pressed[pygame.K_w] and self.player.y > self.vel:
            self.player.y -= self.vel
        if self.keys_pressed[pygame.K_s] and self.player.y < 600 - self.player.height:
            self.player.y += self.vel
        if self.keys_pressed[pygame.K_a] and self.player.x > self.vel:
            self.player.x -= self.vel
        if self.keys_pressed[pygame.K_d] and self.player.x < 900 - self.player.width:
            self.player.x += self.vel

        #Update the player's position
        player_x = self.player.x
        player_y = self.player.y
```

Or alternatively use the player's attributes like so:

`bullet = pygame.Rect(player.player.x + PLAYER_WIDTH // 2, player.player.y, 5, 10)`